# jQuery get n child value outside of html tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get 1.99 as number to run calculations. The dollar sign is a dynamic value.

```js
$(function() {
const x = $('#test').text();
console.log(x);
console.log(Number(x) + Number(x));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">
  <span>$</span>1.99
</span>
```

Comment: a lazy approach would be ```$("#test").text().split("$").join("").trim();```

Comment: @hanshenrik _"The dollar sign is a dynamic value"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the content in the span tag and use what remains.

```js
$(function() {
  const x = $("#test").text().replace($('#test > span').text(), "");  
  console.log(x);
  console.log(Number(x) + Number(x));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">
  <span>$</span>1.99
</span>
```

Comment: Or use the solutions from the dupe target... Why the answer, when there's a dupe?

Comment: @Andreas probably because this answer the op's issue directly and better than the ten year old answer in the duplicate which suggests making an extended function.

Comment: Don't you think OP would be able to extract the relevant part? You could also just add your answer on the dupe to consolidate the possible ways in one question. Almost like duplicates are there for a reason...